# JQuery with jinja2 multiple forms

Tags: jquery, html, jinja2

I am generating forms from a list with jinja2 in a html template but i am not sure how to link up code in JQuery. I can line up the ID's easily but in JQuery I'm not sure how to point to the active form as it seems my JQuery code is reliant on hard coded values pointing to the form or messy code of having hundreds of lines of code for each form generated from a loop.

Here is my generated form:

```
{% set count = 1 %}
{% for chats in chats -%}
<li class="contact">
    <form id="{{chats[count]['chatID']}}" method="POST" action='#'>
        <div class="wrap">
            <!-- get status from get request -->                    
            <span class="contact-status online"></span>
            <!-- get profile picture from get request -->
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/placeholder.png') }}" alt="" />
            <div class="meta">
                <!-- get contact name from get request -->
                {% if current_user == chats[count]['sender'] %}
                    <p id="user{{count}}" class="name">{{chats[count]['recipient']}}</p>
                {% else %}
                    <p id="user{{count}}" class="name">{{chats[count]['sender']}}</p>
                {% endif %}
                <!-- get last message in chat from get request -->
                <p class="preview">{{chats[count]['sender']}}: {{chats[count]['data']}}</p>
                <input type="submit" id="{{chats[count]['chatID']}}Sub" value="Join Room">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</li>
{% set count = count + 1 %} 
{%- endfor %}
```

This is my JavaScript code using jQuery:

```
$('form#contact').submit(function(event) {
    if (activeRoom == null){
        socket.emit('join', {room: $('#chat1').text(), username: activeUser});
        console.log('joined ' + $('#user1').text());            
        activeRoom = $('#chat1').text();//mock value
        activeUser = $('#yourUsername').text();
        console.log("welcome: " + activeUser);
        $("#12345Sub").prop('value', 'Leave Room');
        return false;
    }else{
        console.log('Leaving ' + activeRoom);
        socket.emit('leave', {room: activeRoom});
        $('#log').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('Goodbye: ' + activeUser).html());
        activeUser = null;
        activeRoom = null;
        $("#12345Sub").prop('value', 'Join Room');
        $("#chatMsg").empty();
        return false;
    }               
});
```

Can I pass jinja2 into a .js file? I couldn't find anything reliable, most references seems to be for JQuery within the .html file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out unless i serve the JavaScript file with flask i cant pass Jinja2 into JavaScript jQuery. I did decide to use my Socket.io connection to receive the data i needed from the back-end as a quick and dirty method, its not ideal but it works. A better method would be to do an ajax request to flask on page load. Although if others are looking for methods a third but less than ideal method would be have some JavaScript run on the .html template that the .js file can access.